# Error copiando arrays en función

Tags: c

En esta parte de código:

```
void copicad(char cad2[], char cad1[]) {
    int i = 0;

    while ( (cad2[i++] = cad1[i]) != 0);
}
```

Me arroja este error:
error: unsequenced modification and access to 'i' [-Werror,-Wunsequenced]

Qué es lo que está mal con el subíndice i?

Gracias de antemano.

Un saludo.

Comment: agrega más información a tu pregunta, pon como ejemplo que valores envias al método. Revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que estás haciendo

```
cad2[i++] = cad1[i]
```

Es un *comportamiento indefinido*: ¿ Que se evalúa antes, `cad2[i++]` o `cad1[i]` ?

Una posible solución es:

```
void copicad(char cad2[], char cad1[]) {
  int i = 0;

  while ( ( cad2[i] = cad1[i] ) != 0)
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: Pero por ser una asignación no se debería de evaluar primero cad1[i] y, por último, cuando se realiza la asignación se incrementa i? De hecho si incremento los dos i me da el siguiente error: error: multiple unsequenced modifications to 'i'